# Is it necessary to check for non-zero length when read from a Reader and write to a Writer in Golang?

Tags: go

When I try to copy from a Reader to a Writer manually, I notice that this works:

```
func fromAToB(a, b net.Conn) {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024*32)
    for {
        n, err := a.Read(buf)
        if n > 0 {
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            b.Write(buf[0:n])
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't

```
func fromAToB(a, b net.Conn) {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024*32)
    for {
        _, err := a.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        b.Write(buf)
    }
}
```

So the questions are:

- Why is the check `if n>0` necessary?
- Is this only necessary for net.Conn or for any type that implements the Reader and Writer interfaces?

EDIT: The second snippet runs fine without any runtime error, just that the behavior is not correct. I want to know what is the effect of that `n>0` check and what will happen under the surface when I remove it.

Comment: This is explained thoroughly in the [`io.Reader` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)

Comment: @JimB the docs only recommend how to how to handle the error. The second snippet runs fine without checking for `n>0`, no runtime error reported, but the behavior is weird.

Comment: Yes, you're free to do it incorrectly, but the docs show how to handle the read data and the error so that you get the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a function [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) to do exactly this. You can [see how it's implemented](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12490:12550#L349) for a good example. It works with all `io.Reader`/`io.Writer` types.

Comment: Yes, I read the source of `io.Copy`, that was how I realized where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: without `n`, it will write the whole buffer (32*1024 bytes) to the Writer instead of just `n` bytes, and that's the source of the weird behavior.